# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint - SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-insert

i have a problem, i exec to insert select a table and show me the error:

> (Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 4 The INSERT statement conflicted
> with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_art_sub_lin". The conflict
> occurred in database "A_DEBQ_A", table "dbo.sub_lin". The statement
> has been terminated.)

but the table dbo.sub_lin have 2 field when PK, Example:

```
 CONSTRAINT [sub_lin_co_subl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [co_subl] ASC,
    [co_lin] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

the table art have:

```
(ALTER TABLE A_DEBQ_A.[dbo].[art]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_art_sub_lin] FOREIGN KEY([co_subl], [co_lin])
REFERENCES [dbo].[sub_lin] ([co_subl], [co_lin])
GO)
```

Rows to table dbo.sub_lin:

```
co_lin  co_subl
AREN    222   
PRSP    222
```

I don't know how to solve the error it gives me! Thanks for helping!

Comment: What is the `INSERT` statement that causes the error?

Comment: No one can help you without seeing the rows that are present immediately before your insert statement is executed, the insert statement itself, and the rows that insert statement uses as a source.

Answer (score 0):

In your table A_DEBQ_A.[dbo].[art], it has a foreign key reference to another table. The way a FK works is it cannot have a value in that column that is not also in the primary key column of the referenced table.

If you have SQL Server Management Studio, open it up and sp_help 'A_DEBQ_A.[dbo].[art]' See which column that FK is on, and which column of which table it references. You're inserting some bad data.